# Making a particle follow a path in spriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have created a particle and when I test it moving on Xcode's property window, it looks like this:

[image]

I have added this particle to a scene, made a circle and forced the particle to run that circle using this:

```
    NSString *myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"particle" ofType:@"sks"];
    SKEmitterNode *myParticle = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
    [self addChild:myParticle];

    CGPathRef circle = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,400,400), NULL);

    SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];

    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

    [myParticle runAction:forever];
```

This is how it looks like. Like a block of white sugar candy. The node particle is following the path, but not the generated particles.

I have represented a circle in dashed so you can see the path it is following...

[image]

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: if anyone gets stuck, try adding myParticle.targetNode = self;

Comment: Hi @SpaceDog, mind to help me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382541/couldnt-make-a-particle-follow-a-path-in-spritekit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You sent the particle *emitter* to follow the path. If you want individual particles to run an action, use the emitter's particleAction property:

```
myParticle.particleAction = forever;
```