# With Swift and SpriteKit - emit particles trail following the swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swipe

I saw this question and answer:

[Have particle emitter trail follow finger path in spriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645904/have-particle-emitter-trail-follow-finger-path-in-spritekit)

I guess in general I just want the same but done in Swift. Any suggestions how to cover that code? or how create a new one, so I have a short particles trail following the swipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's simple code for swift, you'll need to add an sks named "MyParticle".

Right-click on the left sidebar inside xcode, pick new file, pick Resource, Sprite Kit Particle File etc.

I tested it with Fire.

```
import SpriteKit
class Game: SKScene{

var pathEmitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle")
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    pathEmitter.position = CGPointMake(-100, -100)
    self.addChild(pathEmitter)
    pathEmitter.targetNode = self
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    pathEmitter.position = touchLocation
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    pathEmitter.position = touchLocation
}
}
```

Comment: What is best method to remove particles when touchesEnded? Ready to appear again with next touch? Thanks for the very useful code!

Comment: Also - this method crashes when you use more than one touch (multi-touch)... Anyone?