# Make particle system follow node path in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I have a particle emitter and I want the particles emitted from the node but I do not want them to follow the node, just stay on the node path.

Something like this: [Have particle emitter trail follow finger path in spriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645904/have-particle-emitter-trail-follow-finger-path-in-spritekit)

But for scene kit. I'm pretty new to scene kit, can you give me some pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got it, I had to set the emission space to world space and now the particles stay behind the node when it's moving.